# GWT - connect two modules via EventBus

Tags: gwt, module, mvp, abstraction

We use MVP with custom EventBus to navigate across the views. One of our GWT module loads an ebook within a view. We have a button named "Expand", which upon clicked, loads the ebook in expanded mode thereby hiding the header, footer, etc.

Let us say the view (UiBinder) with "Expand" button is named as "ShowEbookView". Upon clicking "Expand" button, the ClickEvent is captured and fired to the EventBus. The logic `onExpand(final ExpandEvent expandEvent)` is written in the same "ShowExpandedMod" class.

Everything is okay, but we have a button named "Popout" in the expanded mode, which when clicked, should open the Ebook in a NEW page! We need to abstract the "ShowExpandedMod" class so that it can operate with the EbookId and can be used in the new page.

We have created a new Module with EntryPoint class, HTML page and UiBinder page for this new popout window. I am not sure how to proceed now with the abstraction and to use EventBus across different modules to load the same content ... (with re-usability ofcourse)

I've explained to my best, but perhaps not very clear! Please let me know if you want more details.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you open a new window in browser you basically get a new instance of your GWT app. You can not use EventBus across different browser windows, i.e. across different GWT module instances.

What you can do is:

1. Add an argument to the Popout page URL. This is easies done via "history tokens" (fragment identifiers), like this `http://yourdomain.com/popout.html#theIdOfTheDocument`. Then you can retrieve the token via `History.getToken()`
2. Use DOM to communicate between browser windows: `window.open()` in javascript opens a new window and returns a reference to DOM of the new window. You can then access properties and functions of the new window. This is all javascript, in order to make this work in GWT you'll need to wrap it in JSNI.

Comment: Kind of making sense, thanks ... How can I work in the development mode without having to run the modules separately ...

Answer (score 1):

Try and use [MVP4G](http://code.google.com/p/mvp4g/), in specific - take a look at their [multi-modules](http://code.google.com/p/mvp4g/wiki/MultiModules) feature (which utilizes GWT's code splitting capabilities).

This should make things like multiple `EventBus`'s and cross-module event triggers a lot easier to handle.